# How to prevent duplicate values being posted?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a code that posts details from a form that looks like this. Field that contains `Ampang, Kuala Lumpur` = `area_slug`
[image: Form]

This form then goes into a controller that as a post function to save the values in a table. Below is the code in the post function:

```
        if ( $this->outlet->locations->count() ) {
            foreach ( $this->outlet->locations as $index => $location ) {

                $area = Level2::find( $locations[ $index ][ 'area_id' ] );
                $area_slug = ( $area ? $area->slug : '' );
                $shipping_fee_value = (float)$locations[ $index ][ 'shipping_fee_value' ];

                // two type of conditional checks
                // $shipping_fee_allow_negotiate = !empty( $location[ 'shipping_fee_allow_negotiate' ] );
                if ( !empty( $locations[ $index ][ 'shipping_fee_allow_negotiate' ] ) ) {
                    $shipping_fee_allow_negotiate = 1;
                } else {
                    $shipping_fee_allow_negotiate = 0;
                }

                /**
                 * Update each location belongs to Outlet
                 * Laravel Model Insert
                 * @see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#updates
                 */
                $location->area_slug = $area_slug;
                $location->shipping_fee_value = $shipping_fee_value;
                $location->shipping_fee_allow_negotiate = $shipping_fee_allow_negotiate;
                $location->update();
            }
        } else {
            foreach ( $locations as $location ) {

                $area = Level2::find( $location[ 'area_id' ] );
                $area_slug = ( $area ? $area->slug : '' );
                $shipping_fee_value = (float)$location[ 'shipping_fee_value' ];

                // two type of conditional checks
                // $shipping_fee_allow_negotiate = !empty( $location[ 'shipping_fee_allow_negotiate' ] );
                if ( !empty( $location[ 'shipping_fee_allow_negotiate' ] ) ) {
                    $shipping_fee_allow_negotiate = 1;
                } else {
                    $shipping_fee_allow_negotiate = 0;
                }

                /**
                 * Create Location and related it to Outlet with `outlet_id`
                 * Laravel Model Insert
                 * @see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserts
                 */
                $location = new Location();
                $location->outlet_id = $this->outlet->id;
                $location->area_slug = $area_slug;
                $location->shipping_fee_value = $shipping_fee_value;
                $location->shipping_fee_allow_negotiate = $shipping_fee_allow_negotiate;
                $location->save();
            }
        }
```

So what I'm trying to achieve is to prevent the same `area_slug` being posted eg. `Ampang, Kuala Lumpur` in both `Location 1` and `Location 2` respective fields. I have the idea of getting the previous `area_slug` but I'm not sure how to do so. If there are any unclear details do comment.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Do you want to avoid that duplicated data is **posted**? Then you need Javascript. Is it fine to filter out duplicates afterwards? Then you need PHP code

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Laravel's validation, you can use [`distinct`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-distinct) to ensure uniqueness over all submitted locations:

```
$request->validate([
    '*.location' => 'distinct',
]);
```

Comment: Just read about validation in Laravel's documentations. To be honest I'm quite new to this but what I understand is `distinct` prevents duplicate values, so do I have to define `area_slug` anywhere since the other fields wouldn't have a problem if duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following to have a good quality software :

Create a separate request Validation object called ModelStore with the following command :

```
php artisan make:request ModelStore
```

use this created as a parameter of your controller store function. like following

```
public function store(ModelStore $request)
```

in this ModelStore class implement 2 more function (there is 2 created by default for error code and message)

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'request_field'  => ['LaravelValidation|anotherLaravelValidation']
        ];
    }

    //In this function you can put all your if else validations and returned a validation array
    public function all($keys = null)
    {
        $data = parent::all($keys);
        $data['one_field'] = affectValue;
        return $data;
    }
```

finaly in your controller store function start with this line to have the data array

```
$validated_data = $request->validated();
```

And then you have your data validated and cleaned. in the controller you keep only the logic and not validation.

To answer your initial question :
if you want to have a complete unique slug field than you simply implement it in the rules with the distinct or unique laravel validation.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

when you creating migration set table field as `unique`

```
$table->unique('email');
```

then you searching use `distinct` for query

```
return DB::table('teat_table')
        ->select('teat_table.*')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();
```